# How to change order of my array when exporting to CSV?

Tags: php, csv

The user will choose what specific column to be exported. I am using `in_array` PHP function to search if the column is selected. My problem is, my column name does not match the row values.

The second parameter in my array push is the data of that column.

Here is my code:

```
$values = $_POST['fields'];
$columnName = array();

foreach ($values as $value) {
   array_push($columnName, $value);
}
fputcsv($output, $columnName, $delimeter);
$linedata = array();
if (in_array("Full Name", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_name[$i]);
}
if (in_array("Contact", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_mobile[$i]);
}
if (in_array("DOB", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_dob[$i]);
}
if (in_array("Gender", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_gender[$i]);
}
if (in_array("BUMO", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_bumo[$i]);
}
if (in_array("Address", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_address[$i]);
}
if (in_array("Bar Name", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_barName[$i]);
}
if (in_array("Reward Name", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_rewardName[$i]);
}
if (in_array("BA", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_BAName[$i]);
}
if (in_array("Date Registration", $values)) {
    array_push($linedata, $info_dateRegister[$i]);
}           
fputcsv($output, $linedata, $delimeter);
```

Comment: where does the value come from? from the database? might be better to have a whitelist of columns, then only select columns which users selected, not select all columns and then filtering after

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over `$values` and add the element from the corresponding array to `$linedata` so that they're in the same order.

```
$linedata = [];
foreach ($values as $value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case 'Full Name':
            $linedata[] = $info_name[$i];
            break;
        case 'Contact':
            $linedata[] = $info_mobile[$i];
            break;
        case 'DOB':
            $linedata[] = $info_dob[$i];
            break;
        ...
    }
}
fputcsv($output, $linedata, $delimiter);
```

There's also no need for the first `foreach` loop. `$columnName` is just a copy of `$values`, so you could just use

```
fputcsv($output, $values, $delimiter);
```

to write the header row.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I just put fputcsv after the foreach.